# Remove forum comment title

Tags: nodes

I'm having problems with removing the title of comments on my forum.
I'm using the advanced forum module and the 'comment title' option is disabled. Anyone knows how to remove it? Thanks!

[image: title]

Answer (score 0):

First install the devel module and then check the theme registry to see if the forum form is in the theme registry or not. for more information about registering a form visit this [page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7). as an example to register the comment form you must use this code:

```
function YOUR-THEME-NAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
           'comment_form' => array(
               'render element' => 'form',
            ),
       );
};
```

**When checking the existence the form theme in theme registry make sure that you use the *YOUR-THEME-NAME* as administrator theme.**

Now use the [hook_form_id_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to customize the form.to see the form elements write:

```
kpr($form);
```

now you can hide or change the order of form elements.

[Here](https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-advanced-theming-drupal-7?p=1146) is the video tutorial